# polling the server with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototype

I am building a website that has a system where users can send messages to each other. I would like it so that when a logged in user received a message, he would get some update on his screen telling him that.

These messages do not have to be in realtime, so I do not think I want to push with comet or juggernaut or anything like that.  Instead, I would be happy to just poll the server every minute or so and listen for updates.

I am new to javascript, and I am wondering if there is a slick/right way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prototype has a [`periodicalUpdater`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/periodicalUpdater), which would be the obvious choice in my opinion. Documented example:

```
new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('items', '/items', {
  method: 'get', frequency: 3, decay: 2
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a timer:

http://www.mcfedries.com/JavaScript/timer.asp