# To view all users online in a Ruby on rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does anyone know how I can display all users online in a Rails application?
I have a user model and I would like to view all users that are online at the moment.
For instance, in my users controller I have:

```
@users = User.all(:collection => "status => 'online'", :locals => {:users => @users})
```

And in my views index.html.erb

```
<%= div_for user do %> 
<h1>Online Users</h1>
<%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar.url(:thumb).to_s)%>
<%= user.username %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is: What method can I use to display the logged in users?

Comment: Please provide more info and context about what you want to accomplish, otherwise this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: hope this makes a little sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a before_filter on the application_controller that sets an 'online_at' attribute. Then you can display all users who were online in the last 5 mins.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, your User model has a a status property that denotes whether or not the user is online.

Based on what you've specified, I can't tell if your controller is properly pulling back users or not; however, you can try something like this...

In your controller:

```
@users = Users.find(:all, :conditions => ["status = ?", "online"])
```

And then in your associated view:

```
<ul>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar.url(:thumb).to_s) %>
    <%= user.username %>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Finally, you're probably going to want to move the above code into a partial and then setup an Ajax polling mechanism that will check the server at a certain interval to make sure that your list is up to date.

Comment: that is the problem(How to set up the Ajax polling mechanism?). Any help on that or reference

Comment: how can i make my User model to have a status property that denotes whether or not the user is online.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778658/polling-the-server-with-ajax

Answer (score 0):

We can list the online users(currently logged users) please see this github app https://github.com/mohanraj-ramanujam/online-users.

But you need to ensure that the user is currently seeing the page by use of devise last_sign_in_at.

Thanks